# All possible Combinations question

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The problem is as follows. Amino acids ($20$ different kinds) join to create polypeptides. What is the total number of polypeptide combinations $300$ amino acids in length?

Note: Chains with the with the same amount of each amino acid in a different order only count once ($ABC$ is the say as $CAB$)

I've tried solving the problem for say $5$ amino acids to form a polypeptide of length $20$, and tried to break the problem down by going through the total number of combinations for $X$ unique animo acids with $X \in[1, 5]$, but I haven't been able to find a pattern.

Is there any trick or formula for solving a problem like this? I feel like I am overlooking something obvious.

Comment: Please use more descriptive titles.

Comment: Not sure the question is clear.  For the first, why isn't the answer just $20^{300}$?  Are there exclusionary rules of some sort?  Are you declaring that some strings are equivalent to some others?  I could imagine that, say, $ABC$ is the same as $CBA$ but you need to state all the rules.

Comment: Yes I intended the ABC same as CBA exclusionary rule to apply

Comment: Ok, so then this is a straight [Stars and Bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) problem.  Each "string" is an ordered $20-$tuple and the entries must sum to the length of the string.

Comment: Argh, I want to take whoever set this problem and shake them. The polypeptide ACD and the polypeptide DCA are completely different chemically; polypeptides are ordered. They need a different example.